# How do you generate "l.bc" files?

Tags: alchemy

I have been trying in vain for almost two weeks now to generate a "l.bc" files based on my very own library for building a swc with [Alchemy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alchemy_%28Adobe%29).

I have tried doing (in both alc-on / alc-off modes)

> ar rc myOwnLibrary.a myOwnlibraryObj1.o myOwnlibraryObj2.o

But still no `l.bc` files are generated, instead only `.a` files are generated.

How do I get the proper `l.bc` files generated?

PS. I even followed examples in *[Adobe Alchemy: Compiling a C library to run in Flex/Flash](http://ccgi.codegadget.plus.com/blog/2010/04/03/alchemy-c-library-1/)*.

Comment: your accounts have been combined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have alc-on the entire time, when you're using gcc and when using ar.  For example:

```
$ alc-on
$ which gcc
~/alchemy-darwin-v0.5a/achacks/gcc
$ which ar
~/alchemy-darwin-v0.5a/achacks/ar
$
$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1   29 May 19 16:59 test1.c
-rw-r--r--  1   29 May 19 16:59 test2.c
$
$ cat test1.c
int test1() {
   return 0;
}
$
$ cat test2.c
int test2() {
   return 0;
}
$
$ gcc -c test1.c
$ gcc -c test2.c
$ ls -l
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1    29 May 19 16:59 test1.c
-rwxr-xr-x  1   532 May 19 17:17 test1.o
-rw-r--r--  1    29 May 19 16:59 test2.c
-rwxr-xr-x  1   532 May 19 17:17 test2.o
$ ar rc libtest.a test1.o test2.o
$
$ ls -l
total 48
-rw-------  1   1268 May 19 17:17 libtest.a
-rw-r--r--  1    668 May 19 17:17 test.l.bc
-rw-r--r--  1     29 May 19 16:59 test1.c
-rwxr-xr-x  1    532 May 19 17:17 test1.o
-rw-r--r--  1     29 May 19 16:59 test2.c
-rwxr-xr-x  1    532 May 19 17:17 test2.o
$
```

If this isn't working for you I think you might have a subtly corrupted alchemy installation.  I suggest re-installing it.

Comment: Paelozogt, 
Thanks for the help, it turns out that i had a broken alcemy.